# Android build produces error "Attempt to create a global synthetic for 'Record desugaring' without a global-synthetics consumer."

Tags: android

I am getting the following error message when trying to build my Android project:

> ERROR:D8: Invalid build configuration. Attempt to create a global synthetic for 'Record desugaring' without a global-synthetics consumer.

I am using Java 17, Android API version 32.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out that I was using Java 11 for my Android applications and Java 17 for the other modules that I used. One of those modules used records, which do not exist in Java 11.

Answer (score 4):

To supplement the accepted answer use this by editing build.gradle:

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
}
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '17'
}
```

Drop down lists from Project Structure menu may not show these values, so you have to edit the above by hand.
Also update Gradle Plugin Version and Gradle Version to the latest versions:

[image]

Comment: My project is in Java16, I think I may want to change to 17(because of a warning), but my issue is the next one:
My Gradle JDK was found "somewhere" by Android Studio because I previously downloaded it via another IntelliJ product, so it was already in the IntelliJ folders.
My question is:
If I want to use Java 17, should I also change the Gradle JDK version, and if so... where do I found this version how do I download it(preferable via Android Studio??)?

Answer (score -1):

I had a hard time with the same error, but finally I found the cause was that I had created a class named "Record". I guess Gradle thought it was the default class, and that class was probably an incorrect version of Java or something. My guess is that Gradle thought it was the default class, and that the class was probably an incompatible Java version or something, which caused the build error (I'm a beginner, so I am not very sure).

In any case, I renamed the class Record to something else and the error stopped happening.

I don't know if this is the same cause for you, but I would be happy to help.